# jQuery sparklines iterate over div

Tags: jquery, javascript, sparklines

I have an array of divs and I want to iterate over each div and pass it to sparklines. like so:

```
var divs = $("#wrapper>div");
var data = ["1:2:3:4", "4:3:2:3:1"];
var i;

for(i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
   divs[i].sparkline(data[i]);
}
```

I get the error "divs[i].sparkline" is not a function. But if I do this

```
divs.sparkline([1,2,3,4]);
```

its fine all the divs get the linegraph but with the same data.

Does anyone have any suggestions but how to use sparkline when iterating over divs?

Thanks!

Comment: And what, exactly, is/are sparklines?

Comment: sparkline is a query library for inline graphs(http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about)

Comment: Make sure that you have included that file. Looks to me like you haven't included that script in your file.

Comment: the sparkline.js? yep. because the the second code snippet works as expected.

Comment: and divs[i] is an object (aka a div)? Shouldn't you first add a div to divs and then call sparkline on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `divs[i]` to `$(divs[i])`

```
for(i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
   $(divs[i]).sparkline(data[i]);
}
```

the `sparkline` works on jQuery object and `divs[i]` would be dom node. So try wrapping it inside `$(..)`.

Comment: this is why i love stackoverflow. Thank you vega!